# Template specialization on array pointer with any layer of nesting

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I need to write a template specialization which will work with pointers on arrays (these things: `char(*)[]`). And we will write this code for that

```
// our class
template<typename T>
struct CoolStruct
{
   static void Print();   // will print "Default"
};

//one specialization for sized arrays
template<typename T, size_t S>
struct CoolStruct<T(*)[S]>
{
    static void Print();   // will print "T(*)[sized]"
};

// and one for arrays without size
template<typename T>
struct CoolStruct<T(*)[]>
{
    static void Print();   // will print "T(*)[]"
};
```

And when in our code we will do something like this:

```
int (*arrptr)[10];
CoolClass<decltype(arrptr)>::Print();
```

The console will print "T(*)[sized]" as we expected (considering that we wrote implementation for all methods of course). But what if we will wrote our code like this:

```
int (**arrptr_d)[10];
CoolClass<decltype(arrptr_d)>::Print();
```

In this case the console will actually print "Default". We could write another specialization like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t S>
struct CoolStruct<T(**)[S]>
{
    static void Print();   // will print "T(*)[sized]"
};
```

but I want to find another solution (I don't want to write another dozen specializations when I would need to use `int(****)[]`). So considering we using C++17 standard, is there a way to do such a thing?

P.S. And yes, sorry for my terrible English; it is not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about other pointers, you could do a partial specialization that delegates double pointers to the specialization for single pointers:

```
template<typename Pointee>
struct CoolStruct<Pointee**>{
    static void Print(){
        CoolStruct<Pointee*>::Print();
    }
};
```